# How can I insert a tie between notes in different voices?

Tags: lilypond

I have a piano score with two voices in the right-hand (treble) part.
How can I insert a tie between two notes of the same pitch in different voices?

This is what I have so far.
I want to tie the last note of line (A) to the first note of line (B), and the last note of line (C) to the first note of line (D).

```tex
\version "2.16.2"
\relative c'' {
  \time 12/8
  \key f \minor
  <<
    {
      aes2.~ \mp
      aes8 ees bes' c bes aes~
    } \\
    {
      ees2. s2.
    }
  >> |
  <<
    {
      aes2.~
      aes8 ees bes' c bes aes~      % (A)
    } \\
    { }
  >> |
  <<
    {
      c2.~
      c8 ees, bes' c bes aes~       % (C)
    } \\
    {
      aes4. ees4.~ ees8 s8 s8 s4.   % (B)
    }
  >> |
  <<
    {
      bes'2.~ bes8 ees, bes' c bes aes
    } \\
    {
      aes4. ees4.~ ees8 s8 s8 s4.   % (D)
    }
  >> |
}
```

Here's the output:

[image: Output from the above LilyPond score]

LilyPond gives me the following warnings when typesetting:

```
mwe.ly:18:26: warning: unterminated tie
      aes8 ees bes' c bes 
                          aes~
mwe.ly:25:25: warning: unterminated tie
      c8 ees, bes' c bes 
                         aes~
```

How can I get rid of these warnings and get the desired behavior, as in the following image?

[image: The desired output (ties hand-drawn in GIMP)]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this trick http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/learning/other-uses-for-tweaks.html#tying-notes-across-voices but your per-measure polyphonic structure makes it difficult. Try putting all 4 measures in two voices into a single polyphony construct, then make this the lower voice:

```
ees2. s2.
s2. s4. s4 \tweak Stem.transparent ##t aes8~
aes4. ees4.~ ees8 s8 s8 s4  \tweak Stem.transparent ##t aes8~  % (B)
aes4. ees4.~ ees8 s8 s8 s4.   % (D)
```

and remove the old, non working ties from upper voice.

[image: Sample of result]

Comment: (+1) If the OP is doing this a lot, something like `stemlessNote = { \tweak Stem.transparent ##t }` might make an easier interface.